# How to add image to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm experimenting a bit with the new canvas element in HTML.

I simply want to add an image to the canvas but it doesn't work for some reason.

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="viewport"></canvas>
```

**CSS**

```
canvas#viewport { border: 1px solid white; width: 900px; }
```

**JS**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('viewport'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

make_base();

function make_base()
{
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'img/base.png';
  context.drawImage(base_image, 100, 100);
}
```

The image exists and I get no JavaScript errors. The image just doesn't display.

It must be something really simple I've missed...

Comment: If you want to load multiple images, I suggest using promises as shown in [Loading images before rendering JS canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61336830/loading-images-before-rendering-js-canvas/61337279#61337279)

Answer (score 290, accepted):

You need to wait until the image is loaded before you draw it. Try this instead:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('viewport'),
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

make_base();

function make_base()
{
  base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'img/base.png';
  base_image.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

i.e. draw the image in the onload callback of the image.

Comment: @swogger rather thank ask anything, try out. That worked perfectly. Make sure you check first the img size of the source, otherwise will be cropped unless you use full function `context.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, 200, 200);`. That would draw base_img from 0px position, with draw area of 200x200px.

Comment: This was exactly my case. I was loading some blob data into canvas using `new Image` and wondering why it was always showing me a previous image. Turns out even if I'm loading an image from a variable I still have to wait for the `onload` to happen. Thank you!

Comment: How to add image style ?

Comment: If [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) gives you a ***`This operation is insecure`*** error, you could try adding `base_image.crossOrigin = "anonymous";` just after the `new Image()` statement.

Answer (score 12):

here is the sample code to draw image on canvas-

```
$("#selectedImage").change(function(e) {

var URL = window.URL;
var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
img.src = url;

img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");        

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 500, 500);
}});
```

In the above code selectedImage is an input control which can be used to browse image on system.
For more details of sample code to draw image on canvas while maintaining the aspect ratio:

http://newapputil.blogspot.in/2016/09/show-image-on-canvas-html5.html

Answer (score 6):

**You have to use .onload**

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 

const drawImage = (url) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    image.onload = () => {
       ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

**Here's Why**

If you are loading the image first after the canvas has already been created then the canvas won't be able to pass all the image data to draw the image. So you need to first load all the data that came with the image and then you can use drawImage()

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was mistaken the function parameters, which are:

```
context.drawImage(image, left, top);
context.drawImage(image, left, top, width, height);
```

If you expect them to be

```
context.drawImage(image, width, height);
```

you will place the image just outside the canvas with the same effects as described in the question.

Answer (score 2):

[context.drawImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) provide three ways for your choise.

```
drawImage(image: CanvasImageSource, dx: number, dy: number): void;
drawImage(image: CanvasImageSource, dx: number, dy: number, dw: number, dh: number): void;
drawImage(image: CanvasImageSource, sx: number, sy: number, sw: number, sh: number, dx: number, dy: number, dw: number, dh: number): void;
```

- d: destination
- s: source

---

Or you can reference explains from [w3school-canvas drawImage](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp).