# How can I save multiple IMGs layered on top of each other as one image?

Tags: javascript, html, coldfusion

I have multiple IMGs layered on top of each other (position:absolute;top:0;left:0;), and I need to save all those layers as one solid image.  How can I do this?  The client's backend is Coldfusion.

Thanks, guys!

Comment: Write them to a canvas in the same order and then grab the image from the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use canvas if you are going to do it with JavaScript.

- Adding image: [How to add image to canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011378/basic-canvas-question-how-to-add-image-to-canvas)
- Saving image: [Capture HTML Canvas as gif/jpg/png/pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf)

If you are going to do it on the back end, you will need to do it with some image library such as [imagecfc](http://www.opensourcecf.com/imagecfc/)

Comment: My understanding is that the need is to create a single file on the backend, not layer multiple images in the client.

Comment: No need for imagecfc - CF8 onwards has the [cfimage](http://cfdocs.org/cfimage) tag and a bunch of [image-related functions](http://cfdocs.org/image-functions) ... details of which can be seen on the answer Billy just added.

Comment: @BillyCravens You are assuming a lot with the question that lacks details. :)

Comment: @PeterBoughton  Been like years since I coded coldfusion, when will it ever die.

Comment: The question said "need to save all those layers as one solid image" - saving a file is different from rendering layers in the DOM. Also, if the user needed a client side solution, I would think they wouldn't have mentioned the server-side language used.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty easy assuming you have multiple transparent PNGs/GIFs (I've done this with coloring states on a US map). Primarily you use imageCopy() and imagePaste() along with image objects.

```
<!--- below assumes 600x400 images --->
<cfquery name="election">
    select state from electionResults where winner='Obama'
</cfquery>

<cfimage source='#expandPath('/imgs/us.png')#" name="usMap">

<cfloop query="election">
    <cfimage source="#expandPath('/imgs/#state#-blue.png')#" name="state">
    <cfset img = imageCopy(state, 1,1,600,400)>
    <cfset imagePaste(usMap,img,1,1)>

</cfloop>

<cfimage action="write" source="#usMap#" destination="#expandPath('/imgs/us-obama.png')#"
    overwrite="yes">

<img src="/imgs/us-obama.png">
```

(written without testing, but looks right)