# fade div horizontally with bg image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

whitespace=bg image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbxQZ.png

CODE:
html

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="content">
         <div id="item1"></div>
         <div id="item2"></div>
         <div id="item3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
body {background:url(image.jpg);}
.container {width:100%; height:50%; overflow-x:scroll;}
#item1, #item2, #item3 {height:100%; width:50%;}
```

I have searched but all answers say to use a transparent-to-white *gradient. I have a bg image (not in pic attached - sorry) that I want it to fade out to. I have seen this on other sites, I assume JS?

Comment: This is a very confusing way of asking a question. "whitespace=bg image" -> link... etc... is very Tarzan. I would suggest a bit more time on outlining what you are looking to do, and for you to take the time to make a jsFiddle

Answer (score 0):

[**canvasimagegradient**](https://code.google.com/p/canvasimagegradient/) could help you. It allow you to draw linear or linear or radial transparent gradient effect.

Following code is an example of code to make a linear gradient :

```
ctx.drawImage(desertImage, 0, 0);

var linearGradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, googleImage.height);
linearGradient.addColorStop(0, "transparent");
linearGradient.addColorStop(1, "#000");

ctx.drawImageGradient(googleImage, 12, 65, linearGradient);
```

This would give you something like this :

[image]

Note that you will need to use [canvas](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_%28HTML%29)

Comment: thank you. would i place the <canvas> element around #content? or on top of it?

Comment: I don't have experience with canvas but this post seems to indicate the proper way to do this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011378/how-to-add-image-to-canvas