# Javascript - Show “text” when a certain value was placed in the Input Range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to do something for some time and I promise I have searched in many places, but I have not found a definitive solution. Maybe it's simple, but it's the first time I try to do something like this, so thank you for helping me!

This link has practically what I want: [HTML Javascript change image with Slider bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25936001/html-javascript-change-image-with-slider-bar)

But instead of appearing images, I want to appear certain prices (values). I'm doing a freight calculator, and I wanted it when people put some value into the Range (lbs) it would show the price it would cost.

Example: Value 23 is selected in the Range. Then it will appear: $ 22.00.

Thanks everyone!

```
<input id="valR" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="5" 
oninput="showVal(this.value)" onchange="showVal(this.value)" />
<span id="range">0</span>
<img id="img">

<script>
var val = document.getElementById("valR").value;
document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=val;
document.getElementById("img").src = val + ".jpg";

function showVal(newVal) {
    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newVal;
    document.getElementById("").src = newVal+ ".jpg";
}
</script>
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem, other than `getElementById("")` which clearly doesn't get you anything ?

Comment: I don't understand the question

Comment: Kindly mark either answers provided below `accepted` / `vote up` if they provided helpful to you

Comment: I do not want images to appear, but this:
If the person selects 34 in the Range, then the following will appear: Shipping $ 200.00

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input id="valR" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="5" oninput="showVal(this.value)" onchange="showVal(this.value)" />
<span id="range">0</span>
<div id="money"></div>

<script>
    var val = document.getElementById("valR").value;

    // Caculate your price from the chosen value
    var price = Number(val) + 1;

    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = val;
    document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "$ " + price;

    function showVal(newVal) {
        var newprice = Number(newVal) + 1; // Caculate the price from the chosen value
        document.getElementById("range").innerHTML = newVal;
        document.getElementById("money").innerHTML = "$ " + newprice;
    }
</script>
```

In the code, doing your freight calculator for variable `price` and `new price`

Comment: thanks for helping me. 
Now where do I define the values ​​that will appear?

Comment: Example: If the person selects 34 in the Range, then the following will appear: Shipping $ 200.00

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.getElementById("range").innerHTML= "$ "+newVal + ".00";`

And you have ***missed the `id` in the last line of code***, that's the reason your image file is not getting changed.

you have to write `document.getElementById("img").src = newVal+ ".jpg";` instead of `document.getElementById("").src = newVal+ ".jpg";`

```js
debugger;
var val = document.getElementById("valR").value;
document.getElementById("range").innerHTML="$ "+ val + ".00";
document.getElementById("img").src = val + ".jpg";

function showVal(newVal) {

    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML= "$ "+ newVal + ".00";
    document.getElementById("img").src = newVal+ ".jpg";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="valR" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="5" 
oninput="showVal(this.value)" onchange="showVal(this.value)" />
<span id="range">0</span>
<img id="img">
```

Comment: I do not want images to appear, but this:
If the person selects 34 in the Range, then the following will appear: Shipping $ 200.00

Comment: what is the calculation behind 34 and 200?

Comment: does not exist. I would like to create these numbers. I can write one by one, I just need to know how. It is not a calculation, but a definite number.

Comment: How to create numbers? do you mean you want to hard code `200.00` for value 34? and what will be the cost for other value? Also, If you don't want images to appear, then why you have an `img` tag and why are trying you update its `src` value?

Comment: They asked me for the code I was creating. That was the closest to the desired result.
There are no repeated values, it will look like this:
Range - 1 = $ 10.00
Range - 2 = $ 13.00
Range - 3 = $ 14.00

They do not follow an order, but values ​​that I will create. Is there a way to do this?