# I can't make a clock hand in an HTML5 canvas clock as an image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I found this clock online, and I want the second hand to be an image instead of a line. I am new to canvases, so I don't know what I am doing wrong. When I tried to make the second hand into an image, it remained a line and it didn't move.

Here is the code:

```
var now=new Date();
var hrs=now.getHours();
var mashpoe=hrs;
draw();

function draw() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('example');
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    var c2d=canvas.getContext('2d');
    c2d.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
    //Define gradients for 3D / shadow effect
    var grad1=c2d.createLinearGradient(0,0,300,300);
    grad1.addColorStop(0,"#D83040");
    grad1.addColorStop(1,"#801020");
    var grad2=c2d.createLinearGradient(0,0,300,300);
    grad2.addColorStop(0,"#801020");
    grad2.addColorStop(1,"#D83040");
    c2d.font="Bold 12px Arial";
    c2d.textBaseline="middle";
    c2d.textAlign="center";
    c2d.lineWidth=1;
    c2d.save();
    //Outer bezel
    c2d.strokeStyle=grad1;
    c2d.lineWidth=10;
    c2d.beginPath();
    c2d.arc(150,150,138,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    c2d.shadowOffsetX=4;
    c2d.shadowOffsetY=4;
    c2d.shadowColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.6)";
    c2d.shadowBlur=6;
    c2d.stroke();
    //Inner bezel
    c2d.restore();
    c2d.strokeStyle=grad2;
    c2d.lineWidth=10;
    c2d.beginPath();
    c2d.arc(150,150,129,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    c2d.stroke();
    c2d.strokeStyle="#222";
    c2d.save();
    c2d.translate(150,150);
    //Markings/Numerals
    for (i=1;i<=60;i++) {
      ang=Math.PI/30*i;
      sang=Math.sin(ang);
      cang=Math.cos(ang);
      //If modulus of divide by 5 is zero then draw an hour marker/numeral
      if (i % 5 == 0) {
        c2d.lineWidth=4;
        sx=sang*95;
        sy=cang*-95;
        ex=sang*120;
        ey=cang*-120;
        nx=sang*80;
        ny=cang*-80;
        c2d.fillText(i/5,nx,ny);
      //Else this is a minute marker
      } else {
        c2d.lineWidth=2;
        sx=sang*110;
        sy=cang*110;
        ex=sang*120;
        ey=cang*120;
      }
      c2d.beginPath();
      c2d.moveTo(sx,sy);
      c2d.lineTo(ex,ey);
      c2d.stroke();
    }
  if (hrs > mashpoe){
    mashpoe ++;
  }
    //Fetch the current time
    var ampm="AM";
    var now=new Date();
    var hrs=now.getHours();
    var min=now.getMinutes();
    var sec=now.getSeconds();
    c2d.strokeStyle="#000";
    //Draw AM/PM indicator
    if (hrs>=12) ampm="PM";
    c2d.lineWidth=1;
    c2d.strokeRect(21,-14,44,27);
    c2d.fillText(ampm,43,0);

    c2d.lineWidth=6;
    c2d.save();
    //Draw clock pointers but this time rotate the canvas rather than
    //calculate x/y start/end positions.
    //
    //Draw hour hand
    c2d.rotate(Math.PI/6*(hrs+(min/60)+(sec/3600)));
    c2d.beginPath();
    c2d.moveTo(0,10);
    c2d.lineTo(0,-60);
    c2d.stroke();
    c2d.restore();
    c2d.save();
    //Draw minute hand
    c2d.rotate(Math.PI/30*(min+(sec/60)));
    c2d.beginPath();
    c2d.moveTo(0,20);
    c2d.lineTo(0,-110);
    c2d.stroke();
    c2d.restore();
    c2d.save();
    //Draw second hand
    c2d.rotate(Math.PI/30*sec);
    c2d.strokeStyle="#E33";
    c2d.beginPath();
    c2d.moveTo(0,20);
    c2d.lineTo(0,-110);
    c2d.stroke();
    c2d.restore();

    //Additional restore to go back to state before translate
    //Alternative would be to simply reverse the original translate
    c2d.restore();
    setTimeout(draw,1000);
  }
}
```

The canvas is 300px x 300px

The clock belongs to Neil Wallis: http://neilwallis.com/

Comment: Try pasting the code where you actually try to add the image. In the code above I don't see where you would add the image, you just copied what neilwallis is doing. Check this answer for some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011378/how-to-add-image-to-canvas . You need to replace the code under the `//Draw second hand` comment with your `drawImage()` code.