# How to get img data (like pixel) from an ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, get

I have a image here : *https://tx3.travian.fr/hero_body.php?uid=446*, by using a userscript (with *Tampermonkey*) I know how to read pixel data but this script runs on the page itself, so it has to be open :

```
var img = $('img')[0];
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
var pixelData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(195, 56, 1, 1).data;
```

---

If possible, I want to achieve that from another page of the website, make a ***get*** call and manipulate the `img`, but I only get weird data (unknown encoding or something else) and I don't know how to deal with the result :

```
$.get(link , function( data ) {
    // test 1
    //let obj = $(data).find('img');

    // test 2
    $$("#content").html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + data + '" />');

    // test 3
    let img = data;

    let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

    var pixelData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(195, 56, 1, 1).data;
});
```

- The image is well-load, i can see in "preview" tab, and everything is ok here :

[image]

- But then how to deal with it :

[image]

**Edit**

```
$.get( link, function( data ) {

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    };
    image.src = "data:image/png;base64," + data;   // ERROR GET data:image/png;base64,%EF%B ... F%BD net::ERR_INVALID_URL

});
```

---

**To try :** just open the dev console on the login page *https://tx3.travian.fr/* and execute (the img page does not require login) :

```
$.get("/hero_body.php?uid=446" , function( data ) { console.log(data) });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base64 PNG data to HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409445/base64-png-data-to-html5-canvas)

Comment: @showdev this pointed me to a good direction, I now have an image and I'm able to look pixels, but the image I get does ot fit `GET data:image/png;base64,%EF%B ... F%BD net::ERR_INVALID_URL`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @showdev I've edit my post and add the code I write and the error linked

Comment: @showdev also, I add a `console.log` into the .onload function but it's never triggered, is that because there is no real element in my DOM ?

Comment: Are you sure that the data is returned as a base64 encoded string? It looks like it might be raw image or blob data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182964/discussion-between-azro-and-showdev).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to make an AJAX call to get the image, and as you have seen, making the AJAX call has problems, although [it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36657516/712765). Just load the image as an image, draw it into a Canvas, and proceed as before.

```js
const link = "https://tx3.travian.fr/hero_body.php?uid=446";

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    var pixelData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(200, 200, 1, 1).data;
    console.log('pixelData', pixelData);
}
img.src = link
```

Note that this is subject to [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) limitations, but if you are accessing the image from a page on the same domain, that will not be an issue. (Otherwise you need to have an appropriate [CORS policy](https://enable-cors.org/) on the image and set `img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"`.)

**Note to readers**: *to run the code above while avoiding CORS issues, open the [image link](https://tx3.travian.fr/hero_body.php?uid=446) in your browser and then run the code in your browser's JavaScript console for that page.*

Comment: I'm trying that later and I'll tell you

Comment: @azro The pixel shows up as 0,0,0,0 because the picture is transparent black at the point you chose. I changed the sampling point so you get non-zero data.

Comment: 15h until bounty for you ;)