# Load and download modify img

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I need to download img to web site, then those some layer (img to). This layer placed over my download img, and than i download new img. ([Worked example](http://www.gastreet.com/avatar/#1))
Unfortunately some part of this example on backend, and I can't copy this and use with my own layers((

So question: What i need use to add my own layes on my img, and then download new img. Ho it worked!? THX!)

Comment: Sorry, can't understand. Example is not in english either making it difficult

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6011402/362536

Comment: snit80, Button on top - you downloads img to the page.Then you can chose one of the 4-th layers, and it add to you download image. Like a Frame.

Comment: Brad, I am sorry, but I am don't understand how it work.