# Image not showing up in Html/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to put an image on a canvas in javascript. It is going on top of a box.

```
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "linetime.png";
    img.width = 100;
    img.height = 100;

    document.body.appendChild(img);
```

That is the general code for calling the image. Tell me if you need more context/you need me to put the rest of the code in.

Comment: You need to supply more info. Is the code running? Is the element in the DOM? Are there any errors in the console, such as image not found?

Comment: You should look at your browser's console to see where the error is.

Comment: are you refering to canvas or just an img tag dom?

Comment: Your code is running correctly, the `img` element is injected at the bottom of the body, which is expected. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> That is the general code for calling the image. Tell me if you need
>   more context/you need me to put the rest of the code in.

Basically You will need to "draw" the image into a canvas. 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

[How to add image to canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011378/how-to-add-image-to-canvas)