# Loading images before rendering JS canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I'm writing one of those simple games to learn JS and I'm learning HTML5 in the process so I need to draw things on canvas.

Here's the code:

```
 let paddle = new Paddle(GAME_WIDTH,GAME_HEIGHT);

 new InputHandler(paddle);

 let lastTime = 0;

 const ball = new Image();
 ball.src = 'assets/ball.png';

 function gameLoop(timeStamp){
   let dt = timeStamp - lastTime;
   lastTime = timeStamp;

   ctx.clearRect(0,0,600,600);
   paddle.update(dt);
   paddle.draw(ctx);

   ball.onload = () => {
    ctx.drawImage(ball,20,20);
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
 }

gameLoop();
```

screenshot: no ball
[before comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/514HQ.png)

now I comment out the `clearRect()`:

[after comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwSm6.png)

hello ball.

There's also a paddle at the bottom of the canvas that doesn't seem to be affected by the `clearRect()` method. It works just fine. What am I missing here?

Comment: "What am I missing here?" at least one `}` to begin with. Also, if your indentation was correct that would help to read your code. `gameLoop` is never called. Depending on the two first points, `ball.onload` may never fire if it is indeed inside `gameLoop`, because it's an event listener, and will fire only once ; You'd be better having `ball.onload = galeLoop;`

Comment: @Kaiido I've included the rest of the code. Thanks for taking the time to look into this. I'll study the event listeners

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make much sense to put the image's `onload` handler inside the game loop. This means the game has to begin running before the image's `onload` function is set, leading to a pretty confusing situation.

The correct sequence is to set the `onload` handlers, then the image sources, then `await` all of the image `onload`s firing before running the game loop. Setting the main loop to an `onload` directly is pretty easy when you only have one image, but for a game with multiple assets, this can get awkward quickly.

Here's a minimal example of how you might load many game assets using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Very likely, you'll want to unpack the loaded images into more descriptive objects rather than an array, but this is a start.

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 250;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const assets = [
  "https://placehold.co/120x100",
  "https://placehold.co/120x120",
  "https://placehold.co/120x140",
];
const assetsLoaded = assets.map(url =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onerror = e => reject(`${url} failed to load`);
    img.onload = e => resolve(img);
    img.src = url;
  })
);

Promise
  .all(assetsLoaded)
  .then(images => {
    (function gameLoop() {
      requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      images.forEach((e, i) =>
        ctx.drawImage(
          e, 
          i * 120, // x
          Math.sin(Date.now() * 0.005) * 20 + 40 // y
        )
      );
    })();
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: this worked perfectly! I'm not quite there yet but I'm starting to get the hang of js events. it can get quite confusing

Comment: Yeah there is a learning curve to promises and callbacks. Keep at it.