# problem with clearRect and element rendering

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

the question may seem simple, but I can not understand what is my mistake.

I draw images on my canvas, everything is fine, but at the moment when I add clearRect, the elements are completely removed from the canvas without restoring them. Although the cleanup cycle should happen before the rendering

what's my mistake? everything seems to be simple, but I'm stuck with it for a very long time

App main game class

Game class - responsible for rendering to the canvas and clearing it

player - responsible for the logic of the player's behavior

animation - requestanimationframe is called in this function, on the function passed to it

```
        class App {
    
        constructor() {
    
            this.player = new Player("Player 1", 0, 102);
            this.game = new Game();
    
            this.game.CreateCanvas();
    
            window.addEventListener('keyup', () => this.player.UpKey());
            window.addEventListener('keydown', (event)=> this.player.HandlerKeyPress(event));
    
            new Animation(this.Display.bind(this));
    
        }
    
        Display() {
    
            this.game.ClearCanvas();
            this.SetLevel();
    
        }
    
        SetLevel() {
    
            this.game.LoadSprite(assets.mario, [...player_assets.mario.small.standing_right,  ...this.player.GetPosition(), 16, 16]);
            this.StaticObject();
    
        }
    
        StaticObject () {
    
            for(let i = 0; i < 32; i++){
    
                this.game.LoadSprite(assets.block, [...lvl_1.block.ground.size,  i* 16, 134, 16,16]);
                this.game.LoadSprite(assets.block, [...lvl_1.block.ground.size,  i* 16, 118, 16,16]);
            
            }
    
        }
    
    }
    
    new App();
    
    export default class Game {
    
        CreateCanvas () {
    
            this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    
            this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    
            document.body.appendChild(this.canvas);
    
        }
    
        ClearCanvas() {
    
            this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    
        }
    
        SetBackgroundColor (color) {
    
            this.ctx.fillStyle = color;
            this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    
        }
    
        LoadSprite (src, position) {
            
            const _image = new Image();
    
            _image.src = src;
    
            _image.onload = () => {
    
                this.ctx.drawImage(_image, ...position, true);
    
            }
    
        }
    
    }

export default class LoopAnimation {

    constructor(display) {

        this.display = display;

        this.Animation = this.Animation.bind(this);

        this.Animation();

    }

    Animation() {

        requestAnimationFrame(this.Animation);

        this.display();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is it's related to cache and event onload not firing. [image.onload event and browser cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354865/image-onload-event-and-browser-cache)
suggests to set the `onload` property before the `src`.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
   alert("image is loaded");
}
img.src = "img.jpg";
```

If you want to reuse loaded images, then store them in an array. Then reuse the image from there. See for example:

```js
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
canvas.width = 450;
canvas.height = 250;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const assets = [
  "https://picsum.photos/id/237/150",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/235/150",
  "https://picsum.photos/id/232/150",
];
const assetsLoaded = assets.map(url =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = e => resolve(img);
    img.src = url;
  })
);

Promise
  .all(assetsLoaded)
  .then(images => {
    (function gameLoop() {
      requestAnimationFrame(gameLoop);
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      images.forEach((e, i) =>
        ctx.drawImage(
          e, 
          i * 150 + Math.cos(Date.now() * 0.003 + i) * 20, // x
          Math.sin(Date.now() * 0.005 + i) * 50 + 50 // y
        )
      );
    })();
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
;

// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61337279/3807365
```

Specifically for your question, you can declare a global object `var cache={}` where its keys are the src of images to load. so, for example:

```
var cache = {};

LoadSprite(src, position) {
  if (cache[src]) {
    this.ctx.drawImage(cache[src], ...position, true);
    return;
  }

  const _image = new Image();
  _image.src = src;
  _image.onload = () => {
    cache[src] = _image;
    this.ctx.drawImage(_image, ...position, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't solve the problem ;(

Comment: every time a render occurs

Comment: Wait, are you suppose to load the sprites (images) every cycle of animation? that doesn't make sense. Your images won't be loaded in time before they are cleared. Your question should be how to reuse the loaded sprites and not reload them.

Comment: and what do you suggest?

Comment: Store the images in array, I've updated my answer

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work for me

Comment: I have updated my answer (can you tell?). See the improved `LoadSprite` function