# How to add image from computer or project directory in image-drawing?

Tags: html, angular, image, canvas

> I want to add image from project directory

```
        <image-drawing [width]="width" [height]="height"
                   borderCss="1px solid black"
                   [showCancelButton]="true"
                   [enableLoadAnotherImage]="true" [enableRemoveImage]="true"
                   src="demo\src\app\full teeth image.jpg"
                   (save)="saveBtn($event)"
                   [i18n]="i18n"
                   [locale]="locale"
                   [drawingSizes]="{ small: 5, medium: 10, large: 25, extra: 50 }"
    >
    </image-drawing>
```

instead of src ,i used [src] also ,but i am not able to use these commands..Anyone has any idea...?

Comment: place the image into the /assets folder, and request it from there. `src="/assets/images/my-image.jpg"`

Comment: No, it doesn't work out , Even i am not able to take the image from system also

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011378/how-to-add-image-to-canvas