# How to get an specific image on the canvas with a certain x,y position?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I wanted to get an image on the canvas on a certain x,y position and change it to a random position in a certain amount of time. I have the image URl.

I tried using drawImage function but I got into some bugs.

```js
let ordrawimage = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawImage;
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.drawImage = function newDrawImage(image, sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight, targetX, targetY, targetWidth, targetHeight){
  if (this.canvas.id === 'canvas') {
    if ((image.src == 'https://agma.io/skins/objects/9_lo.png?v=2' || image.src == 'https://agma.io/skins/objects/9.png?v=2')) {
    alert('coins detected');
  }
}

ordrawimage.apply(this,arguments)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add image to canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011378/how-to-add-image-to-canvas)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you check [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp). Basically, you can add an image like this:

```js
const c = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

const img = new Image();
img.src = "https://i.ibb.co/nQ7cRPv/image.jpg"; // image url

img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10, 200, 100); // 10,10 is the position, 200,100 is the size
  alert("Coins detected"); // the original post was edited
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="250" height="300" style="border:1px solid grey"></canvas>
```

**Edit:** I don't exactly know how you can move the image around, I guess you could erase the canvas and re-draw it or use a GIF.